# Assistance understanding why my custom function can be applied to a character vector but not a data frame

Tags: r, function

I have hacked together a function that pulls data from a U.S. government API when provided a character vector of NPI IDs.

```
providerIDs <- c('1982812681','1336201888','1902121692','1164496618','1073557641','1255522488','1679705214','1467719260')
```

I have since pulled a list of thousands of IDs from a database that I need to pass into my function to pull the correct information for.

```
providerIDs <- c('1982812681','1336201888','1902121692','1164496618','1073557641','1255522488','1679705214','1467719260') %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

When I pass this data in as a data frame using lapply

```
x <- lapply(providerIDs[,1], MARGIN = 2, FUN = getNPI)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in providerIDs[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I know this is fundamentals for some folks but a little help understanding how I can pass in a character vector and not a data frame would be a huge help.

Here is the function I am using:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,httr,jsonlite,purrr)

path <- "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?"

# CREATE A FUNCTION TO QUERY THE NPPES NPI REGISTRY
getNPI <- function(object) {
  request <- httr::GET(url = path,
                       query = list(version = "2.0",
                         number = object))
  
  warn_for_status(request)

  df <- content(request, 
                as = "text", 
                encoding = "UTF-8"
                ) %>%
    jsonlite::fromJSON(., 
                       flatten = TRUE) %>%
    data.frame() %>% 
    tidyr::unnest(c(results.addresses,results.taxonomies), 
                  names_repair = "unique")
  
  df_col_names <- names(df)
  cols_to_add <- setdiff(c("result_count",
                           "results.enumeration_type",
                           "results.number",
                           "results.last_updated_epoch",
                           "results.created_epoch",
                           "results.other_names",
                           "country_code",
                           "country_name",
                           "address_purpose",
                           "address_type",
                           "address_1",
                           "address_2",
                           "city",
                           "state",
                           "postal_code",
                           "telephone_number",
                           "code",
                           "desc",
                           "primary",
                           "state1",
                           "license",
                           "results.identifiers",
                           "results.basic.first_name",
                           "results.basic.last_name",
                           "results.basic.middle_name",
                           "results.basic.credential",
                           "results.basic.sole_proprietor",
                           "results.basic.gender",
                           "results.basic.enumeration_date",
                           "results.basic.last_updated",
                           "results.basic.status",
                           "results.basic.name"), df_col_names)
  if (length(cols_to_add) > 0) {
      for(i in cols_to_add){
        df[,i] <- "UNKNOWN"
      }
   }

  df %>%
    select(results.number,
           results.basic.name,
           results.enumeration_type,
           results.basic.gender,
           results.basic.credential,
           desc,
           primary) %>%
    rename(Provider_NPI = results.number,
           Provider_Name = results.basic.name,
           Provider_Gender = results.basic.gender,
           Provider_Credentials = results.basic.credential,
           Provider_Taxonomy = desc) %>%
    mutate(
      Provider_Type = case_when(
        results.enumeration_type == "NPI-1" ~ 'Individual Provider',
        results.enumeration_type == "NPI-2" ~ 'Organizational Provider'
      )
    ) %>%
    select(-results.enumeration_type) %>% 
    # some providers have more than 1 taxonomy, this keeps the primary value
    filter(primary == 'TRUE') %>% 
    # unnesting results in duplicate rows beacause of different address types
    distinct()
}
```

Comment: `lapply` has no `MARGIN` argument, also you can pass the provider ids vector directly.

Comment: also if you want to apply it to a column of a `data.frame`, `lapply(providerIDs[, 1], FUN = getNPI)`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Please add as an answer and I will gladly accept as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` has no `MARGIN` argument, also you can pass the provider ids vector directly. So if you want to apply it to a column of a `data.frame`, `lapply(providerIDs[, 1], FUN = getNPI)`